# Css not working(rendering) in chrome/firefox but works in IE10/Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

It seems like i got a problem that I can't solve. My problem is that either chrome or mozilla can't render the CSS, and for some odd reason it works in browsers like IE10 and Edge. I've searched for quite a while but didn't not grow smarter. I'm fairly new to the front-end scene so I'm a bit clueless.

I've done some front-end stuff before and it worked fine. But for some odd reason it won't work now. The only big difference I can think of is I started to use Visual Studio Code instead of Sublimetext.

Below is the code. I've also tried to have the CSS-file in the same map as index.html file with no progress.

- The CSS is an extension file. here is an image of how my direction looks like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpbmY.jpg

Edit: added my problem! and fixed the text.
Edit 2: For some reason the code works when you run it. But it wont work in my browser or my friends browser(Different computers)

```css
body {
 background-color: #fff5ee;
}

li {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ff6347;
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Headers starts -->
  <div id="header">
   <ul id="navbar">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `It seems like i got a problem that I can't solve` which is? Please explain the actual problem and maybe create a fiddle so we can see your code in action

Comment: I you press CTRL +SHIFT + J in chrome are there any errors? Your code runs fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Thanks for the hints, I updated the text. My problem is that my code is not rendering(drawing up(not sure if I use the term right)) the CSS in chrome or mozilla, but doing it in IE/edge, and also here when you run it(Run code snippet button).

Comment: @AndrewBone No errors in the console for me.

Comment: Renders fine in Chrome so it's probably something in the `main.css` file you;re adding http://jsfiddle.net/4rskjrze/

Comment: The code is identical to what I have pasted here(nothing else is added in the main.css file).
how it looks on my computer: - http://imgur.com/rZyPPZy

Comment: Have a look at the fiddle in chrome, works fine

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Well seems like I had to delete the index.html-file and make a new one for it to work. Not sure why it would fix it in some way. But it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to delete the current index.html-file and make a new one from scratch. Not sure how it solved it, but it works now.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading your imgur wrong but it looks to me like you had your index.html inside the assets directory, when it probably should have been in the parent directory. Maybe IE/Edge just had it cached?

Comment: @DougMcLean Yeah sorry about that, the picture is a bit messy. The index-file was not in assets directory :)